# Merge TSV based on column, to multiple rows

Tags: python-2.7, awk, csv, data-cleaning

I have two TSV files and I want to merge them based on commonality in the first column. The column is without a header, but the data is the name of each company.

I have an awk code that is close to what I want. The problem is that I want to merge the info for every single time the company is mentioned, not just the first time.

items.tsv looks like this:

```
IBM 0.0107  100.0%
APPL    0.0457  98.0%
GOOGL   0.0227  100.0%
GOOGL   0.0197  100.0%
GOOGL   0.0997  90.0%
GOOGL   0.0397  10.0%
```

vendors.tsv:

```
IBM Dec 2011
APPL Jan 2014
GOOGL June 2015
```

With the code I have, the output is:

```
IBM 0.0107  100.0% Dec 2011
APPL 0.0457 98.0% Jan 2014
GOOGL 0.0227    100.0% June 2015
```

Three lines are missing! The desired output is this:

```
IBM 0.0107  100.0% Dec 2011
APPL 0.0457 98.0% Jan 2014
GOOGL 0.0227    100.0% June 2015
GOOGL   0.0197  100.0% June 2015
GOOGL   0.0997  90.0% June 2015
GOOGL   0.0397  10.0% June 2015
```

This is the code I've been using:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
    NR==FNR {a[$1] = $2 FS $3; next}
    $1 in a {print $1, a[$1], $2, $3}
' items.tsv vendors.tsv
```

The order of the rows does not matter. The data is separated by tabs, \t. I hope someone out there can help!

(Note that the awk code is identical to what I have been using, the output is typed up by me, so \t is some places regular space, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was just the order of the input files. With the `NR == FNR` idiom, (typically) the first file is read into the array, and then a line is output for each record in the second file, using the array to "join" with information from the first file. Since you had the vendors file as the second file, three records were read in and three lines were written out.

Similarly it's important that the first file have unique keys to use as the array indices. There can only be one `a["GOOGL"]`, but again by switching the order of the input files this problem goes away as well.

```
$ cat vendors.tsv 
IBM Dec 2011
APPL    Jan 2014
GOOGL   June    2015

$ cat item.tsv
IBM 0.0107  100.0%
APPL    0.0457  98.0%
GOOGL   0.0227  100.0%
GOOGL   0.0197  100.0%
GOOGL   0.0997  90.0%
GOOGL   0.0397  10.0%

$ cat merge.awk
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
NR==FNR {a[$1] = $2 FS $3; next}
$1 in a { print $1, $2, $3, a[$1] }

$ awk -f merge.awk vendors.tsv item.tsv
IBM 0.0107  100.0%  Dec 2011
APPL    0.0457  98.0%   Jan 2014
GOOGL   0.0227  100.0%  June    2015
GOOGL   0.0197  100.0%  June    2015
GOOGL   0.0997  90.0%   June    2015
GOOGL   0.0397  10.0%   June    2015
```